# Google Analytics for iOS SDK 2.0 - What to do with "tracker" variable in app delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

After following the overview found here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/

I am seeing an `Unused variable "tracker"` warning on the last line of the code added to:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Here's the code from Google's overview page:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Optional: automatically track uncaught exceptions with Google Analytics.
  [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
  // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
  [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
  // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
  [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
  // Create tracker instance.
  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-YOUR-TRACKING-ID"];

}
```

`tracker` truly sees absolutely no use past this point and the overview document doesn't really say what to do with it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't need a reference to your tracker (and it looks like you don't) you can remove the warning by changing the last line of code from

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-YOUR-TRACKING-ID"];
```

to

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-YOUR-TRACKING-ID"];
```

A use case for keeping a reference to the tracker in this block of code could be if you wanted to create an event for when a user starts the application, without having to call `[GAI sharedInstance]` to get that reference.

Comment: I am wondering if the intent is to have `tracker` be a global singleton.  The reason I say this is that the example for tracking button touches refers to a `tracker` instance that does not exist if one does not `extern` a global or otherwise initialize `tracker` on every viewcontroller.

Comment: Maybe - I guess I see very little point creating your own global instance of it if the same version is retrieved by calling [GAI sharedInstance] whenever you want to use it.

Comment: OK, after looking at `GAI.h` and `GAITrackedViewController.h` it looks like the error in the sample code for tracking button touch events is that `tracker` really needs to be `self.tracker`.  The blurb here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced hints that this might be part of the design. I other words, no need to explicitly call `GAI sharedInstance`.  I think.  I still have to see if it works.

Comment: BTW, I ended-up getting around the original warning by simply adding `[tracker setSessionTimeout:60];` at the end of the app delegate code.  Your solution works just as well.

Comment: If I could +1 a comment it would be martin's last one where you set the session timeout to "Use" the variable. kind of kludgy but it fixes the error =)

Comment: I removed that line altogether from my AppDelegate. You guys think that's OK? It seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @MattQuiros If you set the tracking ID elsewhere in your app it should be OK. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced) you do have to set the tracking ID before data collection will work. After this, you can use `defaultTracker` as it'll use the first configured tracker ID as the ID to submit with.